# String Alternating letters

Tags: java

Im trying to write a segment of code that will request from the user two Strings.  How can i write code so that forms a new String by alternating the characters of the two Strings.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: is this homework? also, are the two strings equal in length? what happens when one string is longer than the other?

Comment: no the strings are not equal in length...if one is longer than the other it should print the end of the longest one

Answer (score 2):

Simple "dumb" approach :)

```
 class StringMerge
 {
    public static String merge(String a, String b)
    {
     if (a == null || a.length() == 0){ return b; }
     else if(b == null || b.length() == 0){ return a; }
     else
     {
        StringBuffer merged = new StringBuffer();
        int aIndex = 0;
        int bIndex = 0;
        while(aIndex < a.length() && bIndex < b.length())
        {
             merged.append(a.charAt(aIndex));
             merged.append(b.charAt(bIndex));

             aIndex++;
             bIndex++;
        }
        while(aIndex < a.length())
        {
            merged.append(a.charAt(aIndex));
            aIndex++;
        }
        while(bIndex < b.length())
        {
            merged.append(b.charAt(bIndex));
            bIndex++;
        }

        return merged.toString();
     }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter and faster [due to StringBuilder] version of mohaps' approach:

```
class StringMerge {
    public static String merge(final String a, final String b) {
        if (a == null || a.length() == 0) {
            return b;
        } else if (b == null || b.length() == 0) {
            return a;
        } else {
            final int aLength = a.length();
            final int bLength = b.length();
            final StringBuilder merged = new StringBuilder(aLength + bLength);

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < aLength && j < bLength; i++, j++) {
                merged.append(a.charAt(i)).append(b.charAt(j));
            }

            if (aLength != bLength) {
                if (aLength > bLength) {
                    merged.append(a.substring(bLength));
                } else {
                    merged.append(b.substring(aLength));
                }
            }

            return merged.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added length while creating StringBuilder instance

Comment: this really helped alot....i havent really learned arrays yet so didnt understand yanicks all the way.

Comment: @John -- passing down something that'll help you as you grow as a programmer. Always try to get to "a solution" from "no solution" using what you know and then try to optimize it. Please don't read any sarcasm or snootiness into this statement, none is intended :) I always tell this to developers that I mentor in my team and personally have found this a good way to grow one's own skills and understanding

Comment: +1 for using substring() for the remainder of the larger string :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as mohaps and shams (*smile*), but using an array :

```
static public void main(String...args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("String 1 : ");
    String s1 = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("String 2 : ");
    String s2 = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Combined string is : " + mergeStrings(s1, s2));
}

static public String mergeStrings(String a, String b) {
    if (a == null) a = "";
    if (b == null) b = "";

    char[] chars = new char[a.length() + b.length()];
    int index = 0, ia = 0, ib = 0;
    while (ia<a.length() && ib<b.length()) {
        chars[index++] = a.charAt(ia++);
        chars[index++] = b.charAt(ib++);
    }
    while (ia<a.length()) {
        chars[index++] = a.charAt(ia++);
    }
    while (ib<b.length()) {
        chars[index++] = b.charAt(ib++);
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

** **UPDATE** **

A slightly improvement, added a `start` position (default to `0`) to start merge at a specific position from `a`. If `start` is negative, the method will behave as if it were `0`. If `start` is greater than the length of the string `a`, the string will be padded with spaces until `start` is reached.

```
static public String mergeStrings(String a, String b) {
    return mergeStrings(a, b, 0);
}

static public String mergeStrings(String a, String b, int start) {
    if (a == null) a = "";
    if (b == null) b = "";

    int len = Math.max(start - a.length(), 0) + a.length() + b.length();
    char[] chars = new char[len];
    int index = 0, ia = 0, ib = 0;

    while (ia<a.length() && ia<start) {
        chars[index++] = a.charAt(ia++);
    }
    while (index<start) {
        chars[index++] = ' ';
    }
    while (ia<a.length() && ib<b.length()) {
        chars[index++] = a.charAt(ia++);
        chars[index++] = b.charAt(ib++);
    }
    while (ia<a.length()) {
        chars[index++] = a.charAt(ia++);
    }
    while (ib<b.length()) {
        chars[index++] = b.charAt(ib++);
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

Output :

```
String 1 : hello
String 2 : world
Combined string is    : hweolrllod
Combined merged at 2  : helwloorld
Combined merged at 4  : helloworld
Combined merged at 10 : hello     world
```

Comment: +1 for pre-determined size and in-place building :) my code sample was more focused on demonstrating the approach (along with sanity checks) :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user enters two strings of the same length:

1. Make a new, empty string.
2. Loop...
3. If `Index % 2 == 0`, take the character from the second string entered by the user and add it to the empty string.
4. Otherwise, take the character form the first string and add it to the empty string.
5. Stop the loop when there are no more characters to add.